# The wrong lemma for all path connected space $X$ and homotopy definition

Tags: algebraic-topology

In a Path connected space $X$
If $h$ is a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$ and $f$ is a loop with the base-point at $x_1$,
$h \simeq h\cdot f$.

*Proof*
Let $h : I \rightarrow X$. Define $h\cdot f$ as

$$h\cdot f(s) = 
\begin{cases}
  h(2s), & 0 \le s \le \frac{1}{2}\\
  f(2s-1), & \frac{1}{2} \le s \le 1\\
\end{cases}$$

With $h\cdot f(0) = h(0) = x_0$ and $h\cdot f(1) = f(1) = x_1$.
So, there exists a family of maps $h\cdot f_t(s)$ that is continuous( with pumping lemma and
$h,f$ being continuous) with endpoints at $x_0$ and $x_1$. Hence $h\simeq h\cdot f$.

I know this is incorrect because in $S^1$ if $h$ is the constant path at a point $x_0$ (also a loop) and $f$ is a clockwise/anti-clockwise loop with start point $x_0$ then they do not have the same homotopy class they are different elements in $\pi_1(S^1)$.
This means that the set of homotopy paths $f_t(s)$ is empty.
Is there a requirement for $f_t(s)$ path homotopies be non-empty?

This is not clear from the definition in Section 1.1 Pg. 25 Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher of a homotopy.
Thanks for your help...

Comment: In the expression $h \simeq h \cdot f$, what does the symbol $\simeq$ represent? Also, in your proof no formula is given for $f_t$, so the proof is incomplete.

Comment: $\simeq$ represents "homotopic to" and f_t(s)  = 
\begin{cases}
  f(0), & 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}\\
  f(1), & \frac{1}{2} \lt t \le 1\\
\end{cases}  which means there is no other function besides the paths themselves correct? thanks!